# Can any one tell me why the cloud points got from stereo camera(left and right camera images) are only on a flat plat and no depth

Tags: stereo-3d

Can any one tell me why the cloud points got from stereo camera(left and right camera images) using OpenCv C++ are only on a flat plat and no depth.

[side image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssgs3.jpg)

[frontal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9wQc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. It was due to bad calibration.got better point clouds once the calibration was improved